# Wordpress pagination behaviour

Tags: wordpress, url, pagination, permalinks

Recently I added pagination to my site. Using paged param to `WP_Query` and `get_query_var('paged')`. For paginate links I'm using `paginate_links()` with format ?paged=1.
Why Wordpress rewrites this format to /page/1? How to avoid that and leave pagination slug with query param and not like separate pages?

Comment: The default behaviour should be `?paged=1`. If you've modified the permalink structure in the WP Cpanel under `settings > permalinks` that might be the reason.

Comment: @amarinediary I'm using pretty permalinks everywhere. WP makes my paginated urls with query param into url paths. Default link `site.com/?paged=1` wp default converts to `site.com/page/1`. I don't want to use these url paths in pagination.

Comment: Once again check your settings. As the default Wordpress behaviour is `?paged=1` and you're getting `/page/1` i'm pretty sure you've changed the default permalink structure.

Comment: @amarinediary I'm using custom structure like this: `/%category%/%postname%/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed problem. Just changed query variable since page and paged variables are listed in query vars.